# Query com coluna dinâmica spring data

Tags: java, sql, query, spring-data

Preciso realizar um select usando o @Query do spring data, porém preciso passar o nome da coluna por parâmetro

Exemplo:

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Grupo g where g.? = ?") 
Page<Grupo> findTeste(String campo, String valor);
```

Para chamar método eu queria passar o nome da coluna como a seguir:

```
//Pseudo code
page = grupoService.findTeste("id", "1");
page = grupoService.findTeste("nome", "asdf");
```

É possível construir algum método assim no spring data?

Comment: Desta forma não tem como - não sem mudar o core do framework -, o *lookup* de queries no spring data é no startup. O que você pode ter é um repositório customizado, usar *specifications*, construir as queries dinamicamente, usar algo como querydsl, etc. Se não for mandatório ter que usar `@Query` depois posto uma resposta pra ti.

Comment: Não é obrigatório usar o @Query, vou estudar **specifications** e os **querydsl** se puder mandar um código eu agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Na propria documentação você tem exemplo de @Query com NamedParameters:

--

> 5.3.6. Using named parameters
>
> By default Spring Data JPA will use position based parameter binding
>   as described in all the samples above. This makes query methods a
>   little error prone to refactoring regarding the parameter position. To
>   solve this issue you can use @Param annotation to give a method
>   parameter a concrete name and bind the name in the query. Example 52.
>   Using named parameters

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
  User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
                                 @Param("firstname") String firstname);
}
```

> Note that the method parameters are switched according to the
>   occurrence in the query defined.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters

Comment: acho que não entendestes, eu queria passar o nome da coluna, por exemplo:

`page = grupoService.findTeste("id", "1");
page = grupoService.findTeste("nome", "asdf");`

Comment: Ele não entendeu mesmo, a resposta dele aplicada a coluna nem compila...O spring verifica se a query é valida para compilar..

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que nesse caso não tem como fazer isso usando Spring Data.

Mas você pode criar uma classe por exemplo: CustomRepository

Nessa classe você pode utilizar o EntityManager e executar a query conforme você quer, exemplo:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager manager;

public Grupo findTeste(String campo, String valor) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT g FROM Grupo g where g.").append(campo).append(" = :").append(valor);
    String query = sb.toString();
    return manager.createQuery(query, Grupo.class).getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: Hehe, essa era a resposta que ninguém queria acreditar ser a unica solução. Muito estranho não ter essa opção no Spring Data. O Spring traz tantas vantagens e desse jeito não tem como aproveitá-las, como aproveitar o Pageable por exemplo e ter que ficar fazendo limit e offset na mão.